# Highly oscillatory sums

Tags: analysis, analytic-functions

Is there a way of calculating sums of (highly) oscillatory functions?

*Example.* How can we calculate the following series? (At least asymptotics of it.)

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{x} \frac{1}{\sin^2(1/n)} $$

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community! Would you mind typing your question out using LaTeX?

Comment: They say I can't . I don't have enough reputation . @scoopfaze

Comment: Sum of (1/sin²(1/n)) from 1 to x

Comment: I don't really understand the question. For a finite integer $x$ the sum can be always evaluated. However, for large $x$ the terms also become very large and grow as $n^2$. There's no oscillations in that case either

Comment: Well, apart from the extremely small values of $n$, $\frac{1}{\sin^2(1/n)}\approx n^2$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{x}n^2$ is well-known.

Comment: @Yuriy S Sorry for misleading example . But I'm actually looking for the sum of highly oscillatory functions (ex like sin²(f(x))  where f(x) is a rapidly growing function .

Comment: Also , Euler summation can't have a function with oscillatory nature (at least one of them in coupled summation )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\csc^2{(1/n)}=n^2+\frac13+O(1/n^2)$$
So for large $x$ your summation becomes
$$\sum_{n=1}^x \left(n^2+\frac13+O(1/n^2)\right)=\frac16x(x+1)(2x+1)+\frac13x+O(1)$$